# an algebraic variety for a boolean circuit

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, computer-science

There is a polynomial reduction from a $3-CNF$ $SAT$ problem to some system of polynomial equations over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

I mean there is  polynomial reduction $F$ such that for every boolean circuit $g(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ the corresponding system of polynomial equations $F(g) = \begin{cases} f_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=0 \\ \ldots \\ f_m(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=0 \end{cases} $

satisfies the following property: $ \forall (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{F}_2^n: g(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=1 \Leftrightarrow (x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is the solution of $F(g)$.

So, every boolean circuit corresponds to an algebraic set. To use power of algebraic geometry we wish  this set has some nice properties. Is there a polynomial reduction such that every circuit corresponds to an absolute **irreducible** algebraic set?

UPD: in fact it is also interesting to find answers on weaker questions:
is there a reduction to an algebraic variety with poly$(n)$ equations, can this reduction be calculated by using poly$(n)$ memory and so on.

Comment: (1) The property you wrote down is much stronger than just NP-completeness of the problem. It happens to be true for 3-CNF, but for general circuits, it only works under a generous representation of the polynomials $f_i$ (say, as arithmetic circuits). NP-completeness only says there is a poly-time transformation of circuits $g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to systems of polynomials $f_i(y_1,\dots,y_m)$ so that $g$ is satisfiable iff the polynomial system is solvable, without any implied connection between the two solution sets. Do you allow this or not?

Comment: (2) When you write "irreducible", do you mean irreducible over $\mathbb F_2$, or absolutely irreducible?

Comment: (3) As for the update: satisfiability can be determined by itself in poly(n) space, and then you can just output a fixed solvable or unsolvable polynomial system according to the result.

Comment: (1) yes, I understand that my property is stronger but we can do this transformation for a 3-cnf formula

Comment: (2)I want an absolutely irreducible variety

Comment: (3) I do not understand how to verify that given algebraic set is absolutely irreducible or how to construct such variety with given set of $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points

Comment: Regarding your update, a 3-CNF instance may contain up to $2^n$ distinct clauses.  If we work in the TM computation model, any tape long enough to hold the problem instance in a straightforward encoding is already larger than poly($n$), so such a computation is already not in poly($n$)-space.

Comment: @EricTowers, I do not understand, sorry. At update there are two questions: 1) Let $g$ be a boolean circuit. Is there an absolute irreducible algebraic variety $X$ such that $g(x)=1 \Leftrightarrow x$ is $\mathbb{F}_2$-rational point of $X$.

Comment: 2) Can $X$ be calculated by using poly($n$) memory (if such $X$ exists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you willing to allow adding additional coordinate variables $y_1,\ldots,y_m$ that are unused in $g$?  (I mean that, for *any* $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m \in \mathbb{F}_2$, the variety will have the $\mathbb{F}_2$-point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ *iff* $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=1$.  Note that I am asserting the equivalence for an *abitrary* value of the $y_j$, not just with the existence of such a value: so it is enough if I have an unlimited supply of unused variables to draw from.)

If so, the following can be done: find $f_1,\ldots,f_m \in \mathbb{F}_2[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ as you described.  We can assume that the $f_j$ have degree at most $1$ in each variable and are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  Define $\widehat{f_j} \in \mathbb{F}_2[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ by $\widehat{f_j} := y_j^2 - y_j - f_j$ (the minus signs are purely decorative here, of course, and are merely there to emphasize that this is an Artin-Schreier equation).  Since for $z\in\mathbb{F}_2$ the equation $y^2 - y - z = 0$ in the unknown $y$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ has a solution iff $z=0$, in which case it has both $y=0$ and $y=1$, the variety $V := \{(\forall j) \widehat{f_j}=0\}$ defined by the $\widehat{f_j}$ has the property I stated above.  It remains to determine whether it is absolutely irreducible.

Now the morphism from $V$ to $\mathbb{A}^n$ consisting of projecting to the first $n$ coordinates is étale.  This is simply by the Jacobian criterion: $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\widehat{f_{j'}} = \delta_{j,j'}$ (with $\delta_{j,j}=1$ and $\delta_{j,j'}=0$ if $j\neq j'$, of course).  See, e.g., Milne's [*Lectures on Étale Cohomology*](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/lec.html), prop. 2.1.  In particular, $V$ is smooth (or just use the Jacobian criterion directly for smoothness), so to show that it is geometrically integral, it is equivalent to show that it is geometrically connected (see, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118040/connected-components-of-a-scheme-are-irreducible)).

Now this in turn is equivalent to the field extension $L = K(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ of $K := k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ (where $k$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$) generated by the equations $y_j^2 - y_j - f_j$ being of the right degree (namely, $2^m$).  But these equations are Artin-Schreier equations, and by Artin-Schreier theory (Lang, *Algebra*, chapter VI theorem 8.3), it is enough for the $f_j$ to be $\mathbb{F}_2$-linearly independent with a span in direct sum with $\wp K := \{h^2-h : h\in K\}$.  But since we assumed that the $f_j$ were $\mathbb{F}_2$-linearly independent and their span consists entirely of polynomials of degree $<2$ in each variable, which are certainly not in $\wp K$ except for zero, this is indeed the case.

Comment: I allow new variables in your solution because there is a direct connection between $\mathbb{F}_2$-points $(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_m$ in new system and $\mathbb{F}_2$-points  $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ in the original system. Thank you very much, this is wonderful!

Comment: Does the same argument work if change $f_j$ to $\hat f_j :=  y_j(f_j + 1) + 1$ and so this set has $\mathbb{F}_2$-point iff $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is rational solution in the original system and all $y_i$ are equal to $1$?

Comment: @Alexey Yes, that also works: you get a variety that is isomorphic to an open set (namely $\{(\forall j)\,f_j\neq 1\}$) of $\mathbb{A}^n$, hence also smooth and geometrically irreducible like the one I proposed. The main difference with the one I proposed is you get the equivalence with only a specific value of the $y_j$, not with any; but if that's fine with you, of course, it's simpler.